# Boolean variable not keeping current state

Tags: javascript, jquery, howler.js

I am trying to assign a boolean to change when a class `.ion-ios-pause` is clicked. And if it is clicked then it should not run the `player.skipTo(player.playlist.length-1);` line afterwards. However, the `invalid` variable is always false (besides when i console.log inside the `.click()`. I thought that since I declared my variable outside the scope of both statements, that the variable should change states outside of the scope of the `.click()` function as well, but it doesn't. What am I missing?

```
function clickSongPlay(artist, title, url, imageURL) {
    //debugger;
    player.playlist.push(
        {
            title: title,
            artist: artist,
            file: url,
            imageURL: imageURL,
            howl: null
        }
    );
    ////HERE IS THE CODE SNIPPET/////
    var invalid = false;

    $(".ion-ios-pause").click(function () {
        player.pause();
        invalid = true;
    });

    if (invalid === false) {
        player.skipTo(player.playlist.length - 1);
    }
   //////END RELEVANT CODE SNIPPET///////

}
```

HTML:

```
<div><i class="icon ion-ios-play music-control" onclick="clickSongPlay('@song.Artist','@song.Title','@song.URL','@song.Album.ImageURL', this);"></i></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve but when your main function is called `clickSongPlay` it sets the variable `invalid` to `false` attaches the `click()` listener to `$(".ion-ios-pause")` **but it does not execute it at this point** and then it checks the `if` statement.

Your `if` statement is only executed when the main function is called and not after a click and whenever you call that function it will reset the value to false, so you will always end up with the `if` statement executing.

The easiest fix is to get the `var invalid = false;` and place it outside of your function. You might also want to put the whole click listener outside of the function scope.

Comment: I thought: Why is the click handler inside this function? For me this does not make sense at all.

Comment: @DobromirM hey, you're right, it doesn't make sense to add the click function inside. However, pulling it out doesn't fix this issue. I have a play btn on screen, when it is clicked, it toggles to a pause btn. The issue I have is when I click the pause btn to pause the song, the song is reset. This is because the skipTo method is being called still somehow.

Answer (score 1):

your problem is that after `click` event has fired you should do your validation check too. you can do some thing like code bellow:

```
var invalid = false;
function clickSongPlay(artist, title, url, imageURL) {
//debugger;
player.playlist.push(
    {
        title: title,
        artist: artist,
        file: url,
        imageURL: imageURL,
        howl: null
    }
);

$(".ion-ios-pause").click(function () {
    player.pause();
    invalid = true;
    validationCheck();
    });
    validationCheck();
}
function validationCheck()
{
if (invalid === false)
    {
    player.skipTo(player.playlist.length - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: using this method, the song still resets, which means that the skipTo method is somehow still being called

Comment: @JordanLewallen can you post your `play`button click listener?

Comment: the html line that contains the `onclick="clickSongPlay()"` ?